# Can not log in to the dashboard on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I have been unable to login to the admin page of a developed wordpress site. Im presented with a 504 gateway error. I can get to the admin log in page, after entering the correct details it gives me timeout. I now can not log in to edit the page. However the site is still accessible like normal from the usual domain with no errors present. Could it be a plugin preventing this even though nothing has been changed in the dashboard for a few months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means the server is timing out before the processing of scripts completes. Try to [increase the memory limit and maximum execution time](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/increase-memory-limit/).

Try to increase it as much as you can. Start with 256MB of memory and 120 for execution time. If that doesn't work just gradually increase both values.